# pip install error in Visual Studio when using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

I want to draw a **graph** with **Python(ver.3.10.x)** in the **visual studio(ver.1.63.2, 2021)**,
but even if I set the configuration and upgrade the pip version to 21.3.1, a syntax error occurs.
Not sure what is wrong.

This pip code is giving me a **SyntaxError** and **drives me crazy**.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

data = [100,200,300,400]

pyplot.figure()

pyplot.plot(data)

pyplot.show()

pyplot.close()
```

This is error message :

```
invalid syntax (numpy.py, line 4)
  File "C:\Users\Yieun\Desktop\PYTHON_WORKSPACE\선그래프.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot
```

**What I DID** :
When downloading Python 3.x, I **checked the check box** about the **path**.
And **the path** was **manually designated** as C:\python310 and downloaded,
and Visual Studio files were designated in a place called PYTHON-WORKSPACE on the desktop.
Also upgraded the **-m pip install to ver.21.3.1.**

Thank you 4 ur help in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `py -m pip install -U matplotlib`?

Comment: ``-m pip install succesfully done to ver. 21.3.1.`` At first, there was an error message about -m pip install, but now only syntax error message comes up.

Comment: Are you able to run the program using `py [program name]`?

Comment: actually, as I'm a beginner, I don't really get understood. but could you give me the hint how can I get that? I will try my best.

Comment: What's the output when running that command?

Comment: wella, I am trying.. but here comes 2 Questions : 1. which ``[program name]``should I put in my code? like, Visual studio? 2. **in which line** should I put that command? Thank you for your prompt help.

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: Nothing changed from the very first code I posted. Actually, I didn't get how to run the program using ``py [program name]`` and this shows syntax error.